# What is maximum size of Disk for MSSQL Server in Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

What is maximum size of Disk for MSSQL Server in Azure VM ? So far as I know Disk size can be 1023GB at max, but if the requirement is more than that ?

Comment: Why use a *single* disk?

Comment: Better to post this on ServerFault. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use storage spaces to pass that size limit.

Check this link for more details:

[Using Storage Spaces on an Azure VM cluster for SQL Server storage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dfurman/2014/04/27/using-storage-spaces-on-an-azure-vm-cluster-for-sql-server-storage/)

Comment: Or use multiple disks, just as one would do in a physical server. A database can have many files spread across various hard disks, especially when  partitioning is used.